# EF Core: Scaffold DbContext keeps failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The official ASP.Net Core says that the following error can be fixed by restarting visual studio:

```
 Scaffold-DbContext : The term 'Scaffold-DbContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

However the command keeps failing.

I'm running it in Package Manager console following the example provided in ASP.Net core online documentation.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Comment: Please try to execute the command in PowerShell window (first go to the project folder)

Answer (score 6):

I've encountered the same problem. For me it was EntityFrameworkCore.Tools that was missing and did not properly install through NuGet.

Run these commands in your package manager console (`Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console`):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer –Pre 
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre 
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design –Pre
```

And then in **project.json** I added this:

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
}
```

***Important!*** Make sure this version matches **"dependencies"** package (also in project.json). In this example *"1.1.0-preview4-final"* should also be used in dependencies.

If the problem still persists, try restoring your ef runtimes, guidance found here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5549

Answer (score 3):

This is what I begin with when creating new ASP.NET Core 1.1 project which saves me lot of time. If you complete Step 1 and Step 2 did not work immediately, try restarting Visual Studio and continue to Step 2.

## Step 1

Use the following as project.json. Restore packages.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.1.0"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  }
}
```

## Step 2

Run your query in Package Manager Console. The query below connects to TestDb db in TestServer

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=TestServer;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID={Username};Password={Password}" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -force -v -t dbo.Table1, dbo.Table2, dbo.Table3
```